# Layout: Vertically-aligned links next to div

Tags: css

Sample code:

```css
a {
  background: tan;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
<a href="#3">3rd</a>

<div></div>
```

This is the effect I wish to achieve:

[image]

It's easy to vertically align the anchor elements by something like `display: block`, but I have no idea how to put the `<div>` element next to them.

**Note 1**: The above is just a sample code. My actual links can be any width.
**Note 2**: The `<div>` needs to be the anchors' next sibling. It can be any height.

Comment: or just put them in a table ?

Comment: It would be nice if you comment the answers that you don't like, explaining why you don't like them

Comment: Could you please explain why you need a solution and why the div needs to be a sibling?

Answer (score 3):

I would go for a grid:

You can set it to adapt automatically to the inner dimensions.
You only need to set some row and column properties to locate the inner elements

```css
a {
  background: tan;
  grid-column: 1;
}

a:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

#mydiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
  <a href="#3">3rd</a>

  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

It will work also in the case of a huge margin bottom on anchors

```css
a {
  background: tan;
  grid-column: 1;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

a:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

#mydiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#2">This is link 2, now longer.</a>
  <a href="#3">3rd</a>

  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution

1. First we need two columns, one column for links, second for the DIV
   tag. I preferred to take the grid.
2. Used `fit-content` to for fit background on links.
3. The DIV needs to set as `position: absolute`, because without
   absolute position, div will be resize only the first row in the
   second column.
4. For adjustment width of the div, i was create a variable. This
   resizes both the second column of the grid and width of the div.

```css
:root {
  --second-column: 100px;
}

body {
  width: min-content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content var(--second-column);
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  background-color: hsl(201, 27%, 10%);
  position: relative;
}

a {
  grid-column: 1;
  width: fit-content;
  background: tan;
}

div {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  width: var(--second-column);
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
<a href="#3">3rd</a>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The good old float

```css
a {
  background: tan;
  margin: 5px;
  /* all the links at the left 
    above each other */
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto; /* do not overlap the links and stay at the right */
}
```

```html
<a href="#1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
<a href="#3">3rd</a>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't look right if you decrease the `<div>`'s height or increase the anchors' bottom margin.

Comment: @Mike can you show me how https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vrm2odct/)

Comment: @Mike there is only one way to prevent that and that is with a container for your anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Here, check this out.

```css
 a {
      background: tan;
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    div.div2 {
      background: green;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
    <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
    <a href="#3">3rd</a>
    </div>

    <div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Please read the note in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  background: tan;
}
#child-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
#child-2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
#parent {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child-1">
    <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
    <a href="#3">3rd</a>
  </div>
  <div id="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mike i have edited the answer as per the note, please check.

Comment: The above is just a sample code. My actual links can be any width, so positioning is not a right approach.

Comment: @Mike the best and semantic approach is to keep the anchor tags in one div and other element into another.

Comment: @Mike DON'T GIVE NEGATIVE VOTE... 
you don't want to use the flex approach it's different stories. But, the above can also solve using with Flex

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to use `float:left;` on all links as mentioned before. but we probably don't really like float for situations where we also might want to do more complex stuff.

Also you might want to add markup for semantic purposes anyway (like `<nav>` for the links). The only reason I could make up for the links having to be siblings of the div is javaScript, and  bet it will be possible to tune it more performant with slightly more markup around.

To do so you might want to have a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) like so:

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
ul{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li{
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
a {
  background: tan;
}
div.main {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">This is link 2.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3rd</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="main">lore ipsum</div>
</div>
```

No matter how you do it you need a little more markup to solve this if you want a generic answer but not use float. There might be a way around this in certain situations but there is none in a genric scenario. That is if you do not allow javaScript to fix it (which would most likely be an unresasonable solution).

The `li` of cause is unnecessary for your question but in general its a good idea not to position a tags directly but to wrap them. `a`-tags also tend to have unforeseen bugs when positioned with flexbox.

The surrounding `div.container` could be the documents `body` tag instead. Then you could simplify to:

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
nav{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  background: tan;
}
div {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
  <a href="#3">3rd</a>
</nav>
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i used and change this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70773255/10749726) inside my answer.
div element gives links higtht and stays after theme.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
  width: max-content;
}

a {
  background: tan;
  margin: 50px;
  grid-column: 1;
  width: fit-content;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: green;
  
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 9999;
}
```

```html
<a href="#1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
<a href="#3">3rd</a>
<a href="#4">4th long long and too long link. f it Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate nostrum quibusdam cupiditate deleniti possimus sit!</a>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use  position property and display inline-block or you can use display flex

```css
a {
  background: tan;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  width: 100px;
}
.main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
  <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
  <a href="#3">3rd</a>

<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: Please read the note in my question.

Comment: I have changed the code and use position

Comment: The above is just a sample code. My actual links can be any width, so positioning is not a right approach.

Answer (score -1):

Use [CSS clear Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) to make anchor elements not allowed to Float on the left side in relation to other element

Using [CSS Overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp), the overflow of the div is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible, I set it to use `hidden`, you can also use `auto`, but `auto` adds scrollbars only when necessary

```css
a {
  background: tan;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a href="#1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
<a href="#3">3rd</a>
<a href="#4">This is a long string for testing</a>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Flexbox seems to be a good approach. Wrap all the links (anchor tags) in a div element and then wrap that div along with the other div you want to be side by side in another div. See below code example:

**CSS**

```
.parentDiv {
    display: flex;
}

.links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

a {
    background: tan;
}

.otherDiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="links">
        <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
        <a href="#3">3rd</a>
    </div>

    <div class="otherDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

As a fan of using `flexbox`, I came up with this approach

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#2">This is link 2.</a>
    <a href="#3">3rd</a>  
  </div>

  <div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
  background: tan;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent div:first-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.parent div:first-child a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.parent div:last-child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just wrapper your content with one parent class with **Flex** property and it's done. It will solve your problem.

Refer to below snippet code

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}
a {
  background: tan;
}

.otherclass {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#2">This is link 2.</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#3">3rd</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#2">This is link 2.</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#3">3rd</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class='otherclass'></div>
</div>
```